# Universal method to merge duplicate objects in Django

Tags: django

I want to write a universal class to merge duplicate entries in django reassigning all many-to-one and many-to-many references from old to new object. Something like this:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        new_object = self.model.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['inst'].id)
        old_object = self.model.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        for obj in old_object.machine_set.all():
            obj.company = new_object
            obj.save(update_fields=['company'])
        for obj in old_object.contact_set.all():
            obj.company = new_object
            obj.save(update_fields=['company'])
        for obj in old_object.partquote_set.all():
            obj.company = new_object
            obj.save(update_fields=['company'])
        for obj in old_object.trip_set.all():
            obj.company = new_object
            obj.save(update_fields=['company'])
        for obj in old_object.address.all():
            new_object.address.add(obj)
        for obj in old_object.email.all():
            new_object.email.add(obj)
        for obj in old_object.phone_number.all():
            new_object.phone_number.add(obj)
        old_object.delete()
        return redirect(new_object.get_absolute_url())
```

But I don't want to hard-code it manually for all related fields. Instead I want to do something like this:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        new_object = self.model.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['inst'].id)
        old_object = self.model.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        for related_object in self.model._meta.related_objects:
            for obj in related_object.SOMEHOW_GET_QUERYSET():
                // Assuming the field we are looking for is lower case model name
                SOMEHOW_GET_FIELD_FROM_SELF_MODEL = new_object
                obj.save(update_fields=['SOMEHOW_GET_FIELD_FROM_SELF_MODEL'])
        for related_object in self.model._meta.many_to_many:
            for obj in related_object.SOMEHOW_GET_QUERYSET():                
                new_object.SOMEHOW_GET_FIELD_FROM_RELATED_OBJECT.add(obj)
```

Is it posssible to do something like that? The problems i'm facing are:

1. How to iterate over ralated objects `SOMEHOW_GET_QUERYSET()`
2. How to assign field value automatically `SOMEHOW_GET_FIELD_FROM_SELF_MODEL`
3. How to automatically add instance to new object `SOMEHOW_GET_FIELD_FROM_RELATED_OBJECT`

Comment: For this there are always two problems: (a) when are two entries duplicated; and (b) what to do with the columns that are considered not duplicated (for example the `pk` is clearly) one of these when merging.

Comment: @Willem It will be triggered manually via ```url```. And all other fields that need to be merged I will have to be code manually. That I realise and don't even want to try automate this. All I am trying to automate are relation fields.